# Can't find "service_token"

Tags: postman

Is there someone who can't explain to me, how to generate "service_token" from this [API](https://rbaskets.in/api.html).

[image]

I already create get request with "basket_token" using "RESTful API of Request Baskets service." for this [API](https://rbaskets.in/api/version) and it was pretty easy.
But now I have to create get request for this [one](https://rbaskets.in/api/stats) and I need service_token.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`service_token` is a master token that allows to access any basket created in Request Basket service, as well as it gives you an access to the statistics aross all baskets.

You cannot create this token through API.

It is automatically generated when you launch your own instance of the service and it is printed out to the system output.

Alternatively you can define your own `service_token` by using the command line argument `-token`, see description [of configuration parameters](https://github.com/darklynx/request-baskets#configuration).

By the way, `version` (https://rbaskets.in/api/version) is a public part of the API and it requires no authorization at all.